# Galaxy S3 Encryption ruined my photos... recoverable?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, encryption, data-recovery

I put outlook on my GS3 for work and to do so I had to encrypt my phone. Since Encryption, Almost all of the photos I had on my phone are now blacked out. It shows me my different folders and the amount of pictures in each, but i can not view them on my computer or my phone.

Any suggestions on something to try?